# get_access_token in perl after Microsoft Translator API migration

Tags: perl, post, migration, microsoft-translator

[Microsoft DataMarket platform retired on April 30, 2017](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1128340-announcements-action-required-before-april-30-20) and moved the Microsoft Translator API  to Azure.

They have a full example of how to get the new token in [C# here](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/GetAzureToken)

Our old process, however, is perl which I have zero prior experience with. It grabbed the token using `post` in the code below :

```
if (!$token or time > $expire - 5) {
    $token = '';
    console_log("Getting a new access token.") if ($debug);
    my $response = $ua->post(
        "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13/",
        [
            client_id     => $clientid,
            client_secret => $clientsecret,
            scope         => 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com',
            grant_type    => 'client_credentials',
        ],
    );
    if ($response->is_success and $response->content =~ /^\{"token_type":".+?","access_token":"(.+?)","expires_in":"(\d+?)","scope":".+?"\}$/) {
        $token = uri_escape("Bearer $1");
        $expire = time + $2;
        if ($fh) {
            seek($fh, 0,0);
            print $fh "expire:$expire\n";
            print $fh "token:$token\n";
            truncate($fh, tell($fh));
        }
    } else {
        console_log("Failed to get Access Token.") if ($debug);
    }
}
close $fh if($fh);
return $token;
}
```

I was thinking that this could be as simple as changing to the updated url and scraping the old client_id and client secret, something like this :

```
my $response = $ua->post(
        "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken",
        [
               //Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key => newazurekey
        ],
    );
```

I have two concerns though

> 1) The documentation sites I have found and read, one says
>   Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key is a header, the other a parameter is the code `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key => newazurekey` ok? does Perl allow dashes?

Documentation sites : [one](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/57346a70b4769d2694911369/operations/57346edcb5816c23e4bf7421), [two](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/oauth-token.html), [three](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/57346a70b4769d2694911369/operations/57346edcb5816c23e4bf7421/console)

> 2) The response recieved testing the API doesn't seem to have the
>   `token_type:` `access_token:` `expires_in:` or `scope:` like in the old
>   code

I'm referring to this condition

```
if ($response->is_success and $response->content =~ /^\{"token_type":".+?","access_token":"(.+?)","expires_in":"(\d+?)","scope":".+?"\}$/)
```

The response looks like this

[image]

Am I on the right track for grabbing the token correctly or will more changes need to be made?

Comment: `=>` (the fat comma) automatically quotes barewords on the lhs which would not work with dashes, so you need `'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'` to begin with. Do you need to decode the response?

Comment: @SinanÜnür still helpful thank you

Comment: Please post your output as text. Images aren't very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
# Sample code uses five minutes
use constant DEFAULT_TOKEN_LIFETIME => 5 * 60;
```

From a cursory look, the following might work:

```
if (!$token or time > $expire - 5) {
    $token = '';
    console_log("Getting a new access token.") if ($debug);
    my $response = $ua->post(
        "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken",
        [
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => $newazurekey,
        ],
    );
    if ($response->is_success) {
        $token = "Bearer " . $response->decoded_content;
        $expire = time + DEFAULT_TOKEN_LIFETIME;
        if ($fh) {
            seek($fh, 0,0);
            print $fh "expire:$expire\n";
            print $fh "token:$token\n";
            truncate($fh, tell($fh));
        }
    } else {
        console_log("Failed to get Access Token.") if ($debug);
    }
}
close $fh if($fh);
return $token;
}
```

This [comment](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/GetAzureToken/blob/dce055012a22df4c05c46f8d93c93247a1cbc5f8/AzureAuthToken.cs#L19) says token lifetime is ten minutes, but the code sample uses a five minute interval:

> ```
> // Use a duration of 5 minutes, which is less than the actual token lifetime of 10 minutes.
> private static readonly TimeSpan TokenCacheDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
> ```

Comment: Having other issues with the process unrelated to this so I haven't been able to test, but I am going to accept this as an answer as I am pretty sure it is right. (Process is not making it far enough for me to actually test currently)

Comment: If you get specific diagnostics related to this, update your question with the **text** of any errors/warnings.

Comment: Will do, currently though someone else is looking into the issue. It does not seem like the process is making it to the token or api call at this time.